# Spark 2.2 Join fails with huge dataset

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, cluster-computing

I am currently facing issues when trying to join (inner) a **huge dataset** (654 GB) with a smaller one (535 MB) using **Spark DataFrame API**.

I am broadcasting the smaller dataset to the worker nodes using the broadcast() function.

I am unable to do the join between those two datasets. Here is a sample of the errors I got :

```
19/04/26 19:39:07 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 1315
19/04/26 19:39:07 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 25.1 in stage 13.0 (TID 1315)
19/04/26 19:39:07 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
19/04/26 19:39:07 INFO datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol: Using output committer class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
19/04/26 19:39:07 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: SOMEFILEPATH, range: 3087007744-3221225472, partition values: [empty row]
19/04/26 19:39:17 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: SOMEFILEPATH, range: 15971909632-16106127360, partition values: [empty row]
19/04/26 19:39:24 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception  for block isi_hdfs_pool:blk_4549851005_134218728
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:733)
19/04/26 19:39:27 ERROR util.Utils: Aborting task
com.univocity.parsers.common.TextWritingException: Error writing row.
Internal state when error was thrown: recordCount=458089, recordData=["SOMEDATA"]
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.throwExceptionAndClose(AbstractWriter.java:916)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityGenerator.write(UnivocityGenerator.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.write(CSVFileFormat.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:861)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.throwExceptionAndClose(AbstractWriter.java:903)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:811)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:704)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: All datanodes DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.241.209.34:585,null,DISK] are bad. Aborting...
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DFSOutputStream.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:401)
19/04/26 19:39:27 WARN util.Utils: Suppressing exception in catch: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer; Host Details : local host is: "SOMENODEHOST"; destination host is: "SOMEDESTINATIONHOST":SOMEPORT; 
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer; Host Details : local host is: "SOMENODEHOST"; destination host is: "SOMEDESTINATIONHOST":SOMEPORT; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:540)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.abortTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.abortTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:557)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.abortTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:520)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:979)
```

Before joining the large dataset with the smaller one, I tried joining 10 000 records of the first one with the entire smaller one (535 MB). I had a "Futures timed out [300 s] error".

I then increased the spark.sql.broadcastTimeout variable to 3600 s. It worked fine. But when I try joining it with the entire dataset (654 GB), it gives me the error you can see up there (**TextWriting Exception**).

My questions are :

- How can I monitor more efficiently my spark jobs ? And how should I proceed ?
- What do you think is causing this error to happen ? How can I solve it ?

You will find below some information on the cluster, the execution and the configuration of the spark job.

### Some information/context:

I am working on a production environment (see the cluster configuration below). I cannot upgrade my spark version. I do not have spark UI or yarn UI to monitor my jobs. All I can retrieve are the yarn logs.

#### Sample of the code

```
def readCsv(spark: SparkSession, path: String): DataFrame = {
    spark.read
      .option("header", true)
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .csv(path)
  }

    val uh_months = readCsv(spark, input_dir_terro + "HDFS_PATH_OF_ALL_THE_CSV_FILES")
      .withColumnRenamed("NUM", "NO_NUM")
      .where(col("BEWC").isin(
        LIST OF VALUES))
      .withColumn("january", lit("1960-01-01"))

    val uh = uh_months
      .withColumn("UHDIN", datediff(to_date(unix_timestamp(col("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(TimestampType)),
        to_date(unix_timestamp(col("january"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(TimestampType))))
      //      .withColumn("DVA_1", to_date((unix_timestamp(col("DVA"), "ddMMMyyyy")).cast(TimestampType)))
      .withColumn("DVA_1", date_format(col("DVA"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
      .drop("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD")
      .drop("january")
      .drop("DVA")

    val uh_joined = uh.join(broadcast(smallDF), "KEY")
      .select(
        uh.col("*"),
        smallDF.col("PSP"),
        smallDF.col("minrel"),
        smallDF.col("Label"),
        smallDF.col("StartDate"))
      .where(smallDF.col("PSP").isNotNull)
      .withColumnRenamed("DVA_1", "DVA")
      .where(col("BKA").isNotNull)
```

smallDF being the dataframe that is 535 MB obtained after some aggregations and transformations.

#### Execution plan

```
    == Physical Plan ==
*Project [NO_NUM#252, DEV#153, DEBCRED#154, BDGRORI#155, BDGREUR#156, BEWC#157, MSG30_NL#158, SCAPMV#159, USERID#160, MMED#161, TNUM#162, NMTGP#163, BKA#164, CATEXT#165, SEQETAT#166, ACCTYPE#167, BRAND#168, FAMILY#169, SUBFAMILY#170, FORCED_DVA#172, BYBANK#173, CPTE_PROTEGE#174, HOURMV#175, RDFB#176, ... 30 more fields]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [NO_NUM#252], [NO_NUM#13], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *Project [NUM#152 AS NO_NUM#252, DEV#153, DEBCRED#154, BDGRORI#155, BDGREUR#156, BEWC#157, MSG30_NL#158, SCAPMV#159, USERID#160, MMED#161, TNUM#162, NMTGP#163, BKA#164, CATEXT#165, SEQETAT#166, ACCTYPE#167, BRAND#168, FAMILY#169, SUBFAMILY#170, FORCED_DVA#172, BYBANK#173, CPTE_PROTEGE#174, HOURMV#175, RDFB#176, ... 26 more fields]
   :  +- *Filter ((BEWC#157 INSET (25003,25302,25114,20113,12017,20108,25046,12018,15379,15358,11011,20114,10118,12003,25097,20106,20133,10133,10142,15402,25026,25345,28023,15376,25019,28004,21701,25001,11008,15310,15003,28020,22048,15470,25300,25514,25381,25339,15099,25301,28005,28026,25098,25018,15323,25376,15804,15414,25344,25102,15458,15313,28002,25385,22051,25214,15031,12005,15425,20145,22011,15304,25027,14020,11007,25901,15343,22049,20112,12031,20127,15339,25421,15432,28025,25340,25325,20150,28011,25368,25304,22501,25369,28022,15098,12032,15375,25002,25008,10116,10101,22502,25090,15004,20105,12030,22503,15095,22007,15809,15342,15311,25216,10103,20122,11019,20142,15097,20147,20149,25005,25205,25380,15380,10120,25015,15384,11003,10110,25016,15090,25307,15001,25390,15312,10115,25219,15806,15459,12016,15359,15395,15302,12021,11701,10111,10148,25379,15807,10102,25352,25355,12010,25095,25394,20101,25413,15385,25322,28027,11026,15533,25201,25371,10128,11028,12020,15819,10143,28028,10123,10125,11020,25029,10122,25343,15015,12033,25014,12012,25024,25375,11023,25501,25402,22001,15317,12014,16114,20501,15046,12001,12022,10104,10117,12002,25499,10145,10153,12011,15350,15300,10119,25305,15345,25374,11027,25430,28021,25202,10121,28024,25101,28001,15321,11025,25358,15333,15501,25533,15372,12008,11015,10114,10113,10112,15303,15320,28006,22002,25359,10132,15497,25353,11029,25425,15374,12019,25437,11022,15357,20148,20111,26114,25099,25354,10124,25303,11010,20120,20135,15820,15331,28029) && isnotnull(BKA#164)) && isnotnull(NUM#152))
   :     +- *FileScan csv [UHDIN_YYYYMMDD#151,NUM#152,DEV#153,DEBCRED#154,BDGRORI#155,BDGREUR#156,BEWC#157,MSG30_NL#158,SCAPMV#159,USERID#160,MMED#161,TNUM#162,NMTGP#163,BKA#164,CATEXT#165,SEQETAT#166,ACCTYPE#167,BRAND#168,FAMILY#169,SUBFAMILY#170,DVA#171,FORCED_DVA#172,BYBANK#173,CPTE_PROTEGE#174,... 26 more fields] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(BEWC, [25003,25302,25114,20113,12017,20108,25046,12018,15379,15358,11011,20114,10118,12003,25..., ReadSchema: struct<UHDIN_YYYYMMDD:string,NUM:string,DEV:string,DEBCRED:string,BDGRORI:string,BDGREUR:string,B...
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      +- *Project [NO_NUM#13, minrel#370, PSP#82, Label#105, StartDate#106]
         +- *SortMergeJoin [PSP#381], [PSP#82], Inner
            :- *Sort [PSP#381 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#381, 200)
            :     +- *Project [PSP#381, NO_NUM#13, minrel#370]
            :        +- SortMergeJoin [PSP#381, C_SNUM#14, minrel#370, NO_NUM#13], [NO_PSP#47, C_SNUM_1#387, C_NRELPR#50, NO_NUM_1#400], LeftOuter
            :           :- *Sort [PSP#381 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, minrel#370 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#381, C_SNUM#14, minrel#370, NO_NUM#13, 200)
            :           :     +- SortAggregate(key=[NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13], functions=[min(C_NRELPR#15)])
            :           :        +- *Sort [NO_PSP#12 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :           :           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13, 200)
            :           :              +- SortAggregate(key=[NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13], functions=[partial_min(C_NRELPR#15)])
            :           :                 +- *Sort [NO_PSP#12 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :           :                    +- *Project [NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13, C_NRELPR#15]
            :           :                       +- *Filter (((C_NRELPR#15 IN (001,006) && C_SNUM#14 IN (030,033)) && isnotnull(NO_PSP#12)) && isnotnull(NO_NUM#13))
            :           :                          +- *FileScan csv [NO_PSP#12,NO_NUM#13,C_SNUM#14,c_nrelpr#15] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(c_nrelpr, [001,006]), In(C_SNUM, [030,033]), IsNotNull(NO_PSP), IsNotNull(NO_NUM)], ReadSchema: struct<NO_PSP:string,NO_NUM:string,C_SNUM:string,c_nrelpr:string>
            :           +- *Sort [NO_PSP#47 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM_1#387 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_NRELPR#50 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM_1#400 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(NO_PSP#47, C_SNUM_1#387, C_NRELPR#50, NO_NUM_1#400, 200)
            :                 +- *Project [NO_PSP#47, NO_NUM#48 AS NO_NUM_1#400, C_SNUM#49 AS C_SNUM_1#387, c_nrelpr#50]
            :                    +- *FileScan csv [NO_PSP#47,NO_NUM#48,C_SNUM#49,c_nrelpr#50] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<NO_PSP:string,NO_NUM:string,C_SNUM:string,c_nrelpr:string>
            +- *Sort [PSP#82 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#82, 200)
                  +- *Project [PSP#82, Label#105, StartDate#106]
                     +- *Filter isnotnull(PSP#82)
                        +- *FileScan csv [PSP#82,Label#105,StartDate#106] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(PSP)], ReadSchema: struct<PSP:string,Label:string,StartDate:string>
```

#### Spark Version: 2.2

#### Cluster configuration:

- 21 compute nodes (workers)
- 8 cores each
- 64 GB RAM per node

#### Current Spark configuration:

-master: yarn

-executor-memory: 42G

-executor-cores: 5

-driver memory: 42G

-num-executors: 28

-spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=3600

-spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512

-spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2400

-spark.driver.maxResultSize=500m

-spark.memory.storageFraction=0.3

-spark.memory.fraction=0.9

-spark.hadoop.fs.permissions.umask-mode=007

#### How is the job executed:

We build an artifact (jar) with IntelliJ and then send it to a server. Then a bash script is executed. This script:

- export some environment variables (SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, PATH and SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS)
- launch the spark-submit command with all the parameters defined in the spark configuration above
- retrieves the yarn logs of the application

Comment: Please update your question with your current code or a sample, the execution plan (you can print it with df.explain()) and if possible the DAG from Spark UI

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a sample of the code. However, as I mentioned I do not have access to Spark UI. For the execution plan, I am currently doing it, and will edit the question as soon as I have it

Comment: I added the execution plan

Comment: Cool thanks. Your broadcast works, that is good news

Comment: How were you able to tell that the broadcast works fine ? If it did not what would I have seen or not seen instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some improvements regarding your code:

1. Add `repartition` based on the KEY column that you join with `uh`, the number of partitions should approximately be `650GB / 500MB ~ 1300`.
2. Apply filtering on your datasets before joining them, in your case just execute the where clauses before the join statement.
3. Optionally `cache` the small dataset
4. Make sure that the small dataset will be broadcasted i.e you can try to save and check its size. Then adjust the value of `spark.broadcast.blockSize` accordingly,  probably by increasing it.

Here is how your code should look like with the changes:

```
    val uh_months = readCsv(spark, input_dir_terro + "HDFS_PATH_OF_ALL_THE_CSV_FILES") 
      .withColumnRenamed("OLD_KEY", "KEY")
      .where(col("code").isin(LIST OF VALUES))
      .withColumn("january", lit("1960-01-01"))

    val uh = uh_months
      .withColumn("UHDIN", datediff(to_date(unix_timestamp(col("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(TimestampType)),
        to_date(unix_timestamp(col("january"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(TimestampType))))
      //      .withColumn("field_1", to_date((unix_timestamp(col("field"), "ddMMMyyyy")).cast(TimestampType)))
      .withColumn("field_1", date_format(col("field"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
      .drop("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD")
      .drop("january")
      .drop("field")
      .repartition(1300, $"KEY") //change 1: repartition based on KEY with 1300 (650GB/500MB~1300)

    //change 2: always prune as much information as possible before joining!
    val smallerDF = smallDF
                      .where(smallDF.col("ID").isNotNull && col("field_6").isNotNull)
                      .select("KEY", "ID", "field_3", "field_4", "field_5")

     //change 3: you can optionally cache the small dataset
    smallerDF.cache()

    //change 4: adjust spark.broadcast.blockSize i.e spark.conf.set("spark.broadcast.blockSize","16m"

    val uh_joined = uh.join(broadcast(smallerDF), "KEY")
      .select(
        uh.col("*"),
        smallerDF.col("ID"),
        smallerDF.col("field_3"),
        smallerDF.col("field_4"),
        smallerDF.col("field_5"))
      .withColumnRenamed("field_1", "field")
```

**One last remark** related to your cluster configuration, I would try to increase the `num-executors` at least 32 since the level of parallelization in such a big cluster should be higher.

Comment: Thanks it worked indeed ! I did not even set the **spark.broadcast.blockSize** parameter.

Could you explain a few things please :  
- why do I have to cache the small dataset since I am already broadcasting it to the worker nodes ?

- you divided the size of the big dataset with the size of the smaller one. How were you able to determine that this will be a good number of partitions to run my spark job ?
Is it a common practice I need to do when I join two datasets based on a key ?

Comment: Hi there @Ali, 1. you dont have to necessarily cache the small dataset thats why I refer to it as optional. The reason to suggest that is that maybe your program was using it later on 2. I didnt divide the size of the big dataset with the small one I just divided the size of the big one with the size of the ideal partition size which is 200-500MB. Check [this](https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications) link for more details over the partitions size and how to specify a proper partition number.

Comment: 3. yes this is the way to join to big datasets based on a specific key or a combination of keys (the second one is more tricky some times). Check [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html) excellent article from two active Spark contributors :)

Comment: 4. you did well you didnt change the spark.broadcast.blockSize since it seems that the small dataset fits already to the boadcast blocksize. That would be useful only if the dataset size was larger than spark.broadcast.blockSize

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexandros for the help and for the articles it is really helpful.

Comment: I am glad I could help @Ali

Comment: I posted another question with a sort issue I am facing in the same code if you want to have a look :

[Link issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021687/spark-2-2-sort-fails-with-huge-dataset)

Comment: Hi there @Ali :) I will check it and let you know