# Spark 2.2 Sort fails with huge dataset

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cluster-computing

I am facing an issue when **sorting** a huge dataset (**1.2 T**) based on 4 columns. I also need right after the sort, to partition this dataset when writing the final dataset in HDFS ,based on one of the columns used in the sort function.

Here is a stackoverflow post I posted a few days ago describing an other issue I had with the same code but with regards to joining two datasets :

[previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919699/spark-2-2-join-fails-with-huge-dataset)

I used the answer of this post to improve my code. Now the join works fine.

I tested the code without the sort and it works fine. In order to perform the sort, I thought about partitioning the data based on the four columns.

The size of one partition is **500MB**. I have then `2600=1.2T/500MB` partitions.

When executing the spark job, I get an `shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher` error (*see the error logs below*).

My **questions** are :

- What is the best way to sort data in spark to avoid shuffles ? Or reducing it ?
- Could I correct/add improvements to my code in order to perform the sort ?
- Do I really have to sort this way ? Can't I use other techniques like a Group By ?

#### Snippet of my code :

## EDITED

```
    val uh = uh_months
      .withColumn("UHDIN", datediff(to_date(unix_timestamp(col("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(TimestampType)),
        to_date(unix_timestamp(col("january"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(TimestampType))))
      //      .withColumn("DVA_1", to_date((unix_timestamp(col("DVA"), "ddMMMyyyy")).cast(TimestampType)))
      .withColumn("DVA_1", date_format(col("DVA"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
      .drop("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD")
      .drop("january")
      .drop("DVA").repartition(1300,col("MMED"),col("DEBCRED"),col("NMTGP"))//.repartition(1300,col("NO_NUM"))

    val uh_flag_comment = new TransactionType().transform(uh)
    val uh_repartitioned = uh_flag_comment.repartition(1300,col("NO_NUM"))

    val uh_joined = uh_repartitioned.join(broadcast(smallDF), "NO_NUM")
      .select(
        uh.col("*"),
        smallDF.col("PSP"),
        smallDF.col("minrel"),
        smallDF.col("Label"),
        smallDF.col("StartDate"))
      .withColumnRenamed("DVA_1", "DVA")

    val uh_final = uh_joined.repartition(1300, col("PSP")).sortWithinPartitions(col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))

    return uh_final
```

`TransactionType` is a class where I add a new column to my `uh` dataframe based on the value of 3 columns (`MMED`, `DEBCRED`, `NMTGP`), using regex.

Without the sort, and using the full capacity of the cluster, the code runs within 1 hour approximately.

#### Execution plan

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#82, 2600)
+- *Sort [PSP#82 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#252 ASC NULLS FIRST, UHDIN#547 ASC NULLS FIRST, HOURMV#175 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
   +- Exchange rangepartitioning(PSP#82 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#252 ASC NULLS FIRST, UHDIN#547 ASC NULLS FIRST, HOURMV#175 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#82, NO_NUM#252, UHDIN#547, HOURMV#175, 2600)
         +- *Project [NO_NUM#252, DEV#153, DEBCRED#154, BDGRORI#155, BDGREUR#156, BEWC#157, MSG30_NL#158, SCAPMV#159, USERID#160, MMED#161, TNUM#162, NMTGP#163, BKA#164, CATEXT#165, SEQETAT#166, ACCTYPE#167, BRAND#168, FAMILY#169, SUBFAMILY#170, FORCED_DVA#172, BYBANK#173, CPTE_PROTEGE#174, HOURMV#175, RDFB#176, ... 30 more fields]
            +- *BroadcastHashJoin [NO_NUM#252], [NO_NUM#13], Inner, BuildRight
               :- Exchange hashpartitioning(NO_NUM#252, 1300)
               :  +- *Project [NUM#152 AS NO_NUM#252, DEV#153, DEBCRED#154, BDGRORI#155, BDGREUR#156, BEWC#157, MSG30_NL#158, SCAPMV#159, USERID#160, MMED#161, TNUM#162, NMTGP#163, BKA#164, CATEXT#165, SEQETAT#166, ACCTYPE#167, BRAND#168, FAMILY#169, SUBFAMILY#170, FORCED_DVA#172, BYBANK#173, CPTE_PROTEGE#174, HOURMV#175, RDFB#176, ... 26 more fields]
               :     +- *Filter (BEWC#157 INSET (25003,25302,25114,20113,12017,20108,25046,12018,15379,15358,11011,20114,10118,12003,25097,20106,20133,10133,10142,15402,25026,25345,28023,15376,25019,28004,21701,25001,11008,15310,15003,2SOMEPORT,22048,15470,25300,25514,25381,25339,15099,25301,28005,28026,25098,25018,15323,25376,15804,15414,25344,25102,15458,15313,28002,25385,22051,25214,15031,12005,15425,20145,22011,15304,25027,14020,11007,25901,15343,22049,20112,12031,20127,15339,25421,15432,28025,25340,25325,20150,28011,25368,25304,22501,25369,28022,15098,12032,15375,25002,25008,10116,10101,22502,25090,15004,20105,12030,22503,15095,22007,15809,15342,15311,25216,10103,20122,11019,20142,15097,20147,20149,25005,25205,25380,15380,10120,25015,15384,11003,10110,25016,15090,25307,15001,25390,15312,10115,25219,15806,15459,12016,15359,15395,15302,12021,11701,10111,10148,25379,15807,10102,25352,25355,12010,25095,25394,20101,25413,15385,25322,28027,11026,15533,25201,25371,10128,11028,12020,15819,10143,28028,10123,10125,11020,25029,10122,25343,15015,12033,25014,12012,25024,25375,11023,25501,25402,22001,15317,12014,16114,20501,15046,12001,12022,10104,10117,12002,25499,10145,10153,12011,15350,15300,10119,25305,15345,25374,11027,25430,28021,25202,10121,28024,25101,28001,15321,11025,25358,15333,15501,25533,15372,12008,11015,10114,10113,10112,15303,15320,28006,22002,25359,10132,15497,25353,11029,25425,15374,12019,25437,11022,15357,20148,20111,26114,25099,25354,10124,25303,11010,20120,20135,15820,15331,28029) && isnotnull(NUM#152))
               :        +- *FileScan csv [UHDIN_YYYYMMDD#151,NUM#152,DEV#153,DEBCRED#154,BDGRORI#155,BDGREUR#156,BEWC#157,MSG30_NL#158,SCAPMV#159,USERID#160,MMED#161,TNUM#162,NMTGP#163,BKA#164,CATEXT#165,SEQETAT#166,ACCTYPE#167,BRAND#168,FAMILY#169,SUBFAMILY#170,DVA#171,FORCED_DVA#172,BYBANK#173,CPTE_PROTEGE#174,... 26 more fields] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(BEWC, [25003,25302,25114,20113,12017,20108,25046,12018,15379,15358,11011,20114,10118,12003,25..., ReadSchema: struct<UHDIN_YYYYMMDD:string,NUM:string,DEV:string,DEBCRED:string,BDGRORI:string,BDGREUR:string,B...
               +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
                  +- *Project [NO_NUM#13, PSP#82, minrel#370, Label#105, StartDate#106]
                     +- *SortMergeJoin [PSP#381], [PSP#82], Inner
                        :- *Sort [PSP#381 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#381, 200)
                        :     +- *Project [PSP#381, NO_NUM#13, minrel#370]
                        :        +- SortMergeJoin [PSP#381, C_SNUM#14, minrel#370, NO_NUM#13], [NO_PSP#47, C_SNUM_1#387, C_NRELPR#50, NO_NUM_1#400], LeftOuter
                        :           :- *Sort [PSP#381 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, minrel#370 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#381, C_SNUM#14, minrel#370, NO_NUM#13, 200)
                        :           :     +- SortAggregate(key=[NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13], functions=[min(C_NRELPR#15)])
                        :           :        +- *Sort [NO_PSP#12 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        :           :           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13, 200)
                        :           :              +- SortAggregate(key=[NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13], functions=[partial_min(C_NRELPR#15)])
                        :           :                 +- *Sort [NO_PSP#12 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM#13 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        :           :                    +- *Project [NO_PSP#12, C_SNUM#14, NO_NUM#13, C_NRELPR#15]
                        :           :                       +- *Filter (((C_NRELPR#15 IN (001,006) && C_SNUM#14 IN (030,033)) && isnotnull(NO_NUM#13)) && isnotnull(NO_PSP#12))
                        :           :                          +- *FileScan csv [NO_PSP#12,NO_NUM#13,C_SNUM#14,c_nrelpr#15] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(c_nrelpr, [001,006]), In(C_SNUM, [030,033]), IsNotNull(NO_NUM), IsNotNull(NO_PSP)], ReadSchema: struct<NO_PSP:string,NO_NUM:string,C_SNUM:string,c_nrelpr:string>
                        :           +- *Sort [NO_PSP#47 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_SNUM_1#387 ASC NULLS FIRST, C_NRELPR#50 ASC NULLS FIRST, NO_NUM_1#400 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(NO_PSP#47, C_SNUM_1#387, C_NRELPR#50, NO_NUM_1#400, 200)
                        :                 +- *Project [NO_PSP#47, NO_NUM#48 AS NO_NUM_1#400, C_SNUM#49 AS C_SNUM_1#387, c_nrelpr#50]
                        :                    +- *FileScan csv [NO_PSP#47,NO_NUM#48,C_SNUM#49,c_nrelpr#50] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<NO_PSP:string,NO_NUM:string,C_SNUM:string,c_nrelpr:string>
                        +- *Sort [PSP#82 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(PSP#82, 200)
                              +- *Project [PSP#82, Label#105, StartDate#106]
                                 +- *Filter isnotnull(PSP#82)
                                    +- *FileScan csv [PSP#82,Label#105,StartDate#106] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[SOMEHOST:SOMEPORT/SOMEPATH, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(PSP)], ReadSchema: struct<PSP:string,Label:string,StartDate:string>
```

Here is the main error(s) I got when launching the job with the sort :

```
19/05/06 18:02:25 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 214 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.sendRequest(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchUpToMaxBytes(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.initialize(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.<init>(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ShuffledRowRDD.compute(ShuffledRowRDD.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
19/05/06 18:02:25 INFO shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Retrying fetch (1/3) for 214 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
19/05/06 18:02:25 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 6 remote fetches in 13 ms
19/05/06 18:02:28 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 408.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 6696). 1733 bytes result sent to driver
19/05/06 18:02:28 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 6816
19/05/06 18:02:28 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 466.1 in stage 14.0 (TID 6816)
19/05/06 18:02:28 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 5073 non-empty blocks out of 5089 blocks
19/05/06 18:02:28 INFO client.TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT, creating a new one.
19/05/06 18:02:28 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 82 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.sendRequest(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchUpToMaxBytes(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.initialize(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.<init>(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ShuffledRowRDD.compute(ShuffledRowRDD.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

## EDITED

An other type of error :

```
19/05/06 18:06:16 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 309.1 in stage 13.1 (TID 7592)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /applis/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/MYUSER/appcache/application_1555263602441_0123/blockmgr-aa586b76-ff58-4f88-b168-288c3e1b9f61/3c/temp_shuffle_ea967624-f633-4481-9a05-249b561e3c38 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:124)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:114)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java:202)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files.copy(Files.java:436)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files.move(Files.java:651)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.mergeSpills(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:277)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.closeAndWriteOutput(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/05/06 18:06:16 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 502.1 in stage 13.1 (TID 7599)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /applis/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/MYUSER/appcache/application_1555263602441_0123/blockmgr-aa586b76-ff58-4f88-b168-288c3e1b9f61/34/temp_shuffle_dd202cd1-ad8f-41c4-b4d1-d79621cd169e (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.writeSortedFile(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:201)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.closeAndGetSpills(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:405)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.closeAndWriteOutput(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:209)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/05/06 18:06:16 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 200.2 in stage 13.1 (TID 7568). 2826 bytes result sent to driver
19/05/06 18:06:16 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
19/05/06 18:06:16 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

### Some information/context:

I am working on a production environment (see the cluster configuration below). I cannot upgrade my spark version. I do not have spark UI or yarn UI to monitor my jobs. All I can retrieve are the yarn logs.

#### Spark Version: 2.2

#### Cluster configuration:

- 21 compute nodes (workers)
- 8 cores each
- 64 GB RAM per node

#### Current Spark configuration:

-master: yarn

-executor-memory: 42G

-executor-cores: 5

-driver memory: 42G

-num-executors: 32

-spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=3600

-spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512

-spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2400

-spark.driver.maxResultSize=500m

-spark.memory.storageFraction=0.3

-spark.memory.fraction=0.9

-spark.hadoop.fs.permissions.umask-mode=007

#### How is the job executed:

We build an artifact (jar) with IntelliJ and then send it to a server. Then a bash script is executed. This script:

- export some environment variables (SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, PATH and SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS)
- launch the spark-submit command with all the parameters defined in the spark configuration above
- retrieves the yarn logs of the application

Comment: `SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT` - that doesn't look right, perhaps spark cluster is not configured correctly!

Comment: Hello @avloss thanks for the quick response. I modified those fields myself. These are not the correct values :)

Comment: did you check why`SOMEHOST/SOMEADDRESS:SOMEPORT` was not responding? was that an executor machine? external shuffle node (are you using shuffle service)?

Comment: Hi @Ali, quick observations/question. Is it really necessary to re-partition so many times? The first re-partition on uh `repartition(1300,col("MMED"),col("DEBCRED"),col("NMTGP"))` is used by `transform(uh)` and then the 2nd one by the join is that correct?.   Also why are you sorting on all these cols `col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")` is that really a requirement? One last question, why you do `uh_sorted.repartition(2600,col("PSP"))` this will shuffle the data once more and therefore cancel the previous sorting?

Comment: Hello @_shay the node was down due to the fact that the yarn usercache on the machine was using the full disk space of this machine. Hence the node went down.

I don't know if I am using the external shuffle service (I did not set anything for that)

Comment: Hi @AlexandrosBiratsis Indeed I do not think it I need to repartition that often. I first repartitioned based on `col("MMED"),col("DEBCRED"),col("NMTGP")` because it was taking me more than 2 hours to only perform the `transform` operation. 

    For the sorting on `col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")`, I actually changed my code (I will update it in the post). What I do now is : 
- repartition based on `PSP`
- apply the function `sortWithinPartitions` on `col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")` in the partitioned dataframe (I guess I reduce the shuffles by doing it)

Comment: Code **updated** and logs **added**. However, the behaviour is the same as in the first case : all of my nodes start to go down one by one after the job was launched for 30-40 mins (the yarn usercache on the nodes gets filled in by the shuffled data (seen in the logs)

Comment: Hi Ali, `sortWithinPartitions` I dont think it will help in this case. sortWithinPartitions is useful before executing a `sort_merge_join`. You mentioned that your data is 1.2TB which dataset has that size?

Comment: Hello @Alexandros the `uh_joined ` dataset  is `1.2T` (`uh` being `650GB ` and smallDF being `535MB`). The key I am joining the big dataset with the smaller one is not unique hence the size of the `uh_joined ` dataset.  

Just after the join, I need to sort the data based on `col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN") and col("HOURMV")`. I also need when writing the final file to partition it by `col("PSP")`

Comment: Hi Ali, could you try  the changes so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort the data successfully (and then to run the entire code) using a significant part of the answer posted by @Alexandros.

I however did some changes in terms of configurations in the cluster :

- I increased the Executor memory to 45 G (it was 42 G)
- I changed the spark parameter `--executor-memory` increasing it to `45G` instead of `42G`
- I increased the number of `executors` to `40`
- I also increased on each node the disk space of `/applis/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/MYUSER/`, adding `20-25G` (there was a bit less than 50 G available on each node for this folder). This is the `yarn usercache` where Spark writes intermediary shuffled blocks of data. Since I have a dataset of 1.2T, and I have 21 nodes, I need approximately `60-65G` of disk space on each node when the data is distributed across the nodes.

I also used the `sortWithinPartition` function (it was working fine with this function but it fails with the classic sort function). Besides, I only need to sort each partition since I partition based on `PSP` (if the dataset is not sorted based on `PSP`, it's fine).

Below is the code :

```
val uh = uh_months
  .withColumn("UHDIN", datediff(to_date(unix_timestamp(col("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(TimestampType)),
    to_date(unix_timestamp(col("january"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(TimestampType))))
  //      .withColumn("DVA_1", to_date((unix_timestamp(col("DVA"), "ddMMMyyyy")).cast(TimestampType)))
  .withColumn("DVA_1", date_format(col("DVA"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
  .drop("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD")
  .drop("january")
  .drop("DVA")
  .repartition(3000, col("NO_NUM"))
  .persist()

val uh_flag_comment = new TransactionType().transform(uh)

val uh_joined = uh_flag_comment.join(broadcast(smallDF), "NO_NUM")
  .select(
    uh_flag_comment.col("*"),
    kl_holdmand_pruned.col("PSP"),
    kl_holdmand_pruned.col("minrel"),
    kl_holdmand_pruned.col("TerroLabel"),
    kl_holdmand_pruned.col("TerroStartDate"))
  .withColumnRenamed("DVA_1", "DVA")

smallDF.unpersist()
uh.unpersist()

val uh_to_be_sorted = uh_joined.repartition(3000, col("PSP"))
val uh_final = uh_to_be_sorted.sortWithinPartitions(col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))

uh_final
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for your case:

- **change 1**: repartition based on the larger generated dataset 1.2TB. Also I removed the `repartition(col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))` at this point since it will be overwritten from the next repartition("NO_NUM") and hence it is redundant.
- **change 2**: use persist to save the data that we just partitioned in order to avoid repartitioning over and over again for the same dataframe (please check the links from the previous post on how this works)
- **change 3**: removed `uh_flag_comment.repartition(1300,col("NO_NUM"))` since it seems redundant to me. Although that **would be useful only if** `TransactionType().transform(uh)` is causing reshuffling, for instance is internally doing a join or groupBy! Such operation would modify the partition key we set on the previous step with `repartition(2600, col("NO_NUM")`.
- **change 4**: repartition with `col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")` since this will be the partition key that will be used by the orderBy therefore these two should be identical
- **change 5**: orderBy with `col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")`
- **change 6**: increase the executors num to 40

```scala
val uh = uh_months
      .withColumn("UHDIN", datediff(to_date(unix_timestamp(col("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(TimestampType)),
        to_date(unix_timestamp(col("january"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(TimestampType))))
      //      .withColumn("DVA_1", to_date((unix_timestamp(col("DVA"), "ddMMMyyyy")).cast(TimestampType)))
      .withColumn("DVA_1", date_format(col("DVA"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
      .drop("UHDIN_YYYYMMDD")
      .drop("january")
      .drop("DVA")
      .repartition(2600, col("NO_NUM"))//change 1: repartition based on the larger generated dataset also removed repartition(col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")) since it will be overriten from the next repartition()
      .persist() //change 2: save your keys (please check the links from the previous post on how this works)

    val uh_flag_comment = new TransactionType().transform(uh)

    //change 3: the previous repartition was redudant 
    val uh_joined = uh_flag_comment.join(broadcast(smallDF), "NO_NUM")
      .select(
        uh.col("*"),
        smallDF.col("PSP"),
        smallDF.col("minrel"),
        smallDF.col("Label"),
        smallDF.col("StartDate"))
      .withColumnRenamed("DVA_1", "DVA")
      .repartition(2600, col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))//change 4: this is the partition key that will be used by the orderBy therefore these two should be identical
      .persist()//optional, try to remove it as well

    // change 5: removed redudant repartition and addded the same partition information as above   
    val uh_final = uh_joined.orderBy(col("PSP), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))

    return uh_final
```

Good luck and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hello @Alexandros thank you for your answer. However, I need to write the `uh_final` data repartitioned by `PSP` (what I did is that I repartitioned based on `col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV")` and I ordered by the same columns). That is why I thought about repartitioning by `PSP` using afterwards the `sortWithinPartitions` function.

The result is still the same with the changes : all the nodes start to go down one by one, 30 mins after the execution of the job. I think the yarn usercache on the nodes is getting filled in by the shuffled data.

Comment: Hello @Ali then you have to include PSP key together with other three so `repartition(2600, col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))` and then `orderBy(col("PSP"), col("NO_NUM"), col("UHDIN"), col("HOURMV"))` you should not seperate the keys and use them separately because then you change your partition key and override the previous one. I will change the code accordignly

Comment: Hello @Alexandros that is exactly what I did :)

Comment: I actually launched the job with the code you modified @Alexandros and like I said it failed with the nodes going down one by one after 30 mins because of the shuffled data filling the yarn usercache on each node.

Comment: ok try to find out the step that fails on the DAG or by excluding steps (you can start with the last one). This key is probably the issue since it will be very expensive! Are you sure you need all these keys for the sorting?

Comment: Also Ali, you can try to increase the partition number to >=3000 along with the executors_num to 40

Comment: Hello @Alexandros I applied the changes but I still get the same errors. Even without the sort, it fails. (It works without the sort but by adding `repartition(1300,col("MMED"),col("DEBCRED"),col("NMTGP"))` like in my previous code).

What I am doing now is writing to HDFS intermediary results (the dataset joined, and not repartitioned). After that, I will partition it by `PSP` and write it to HDFS (I need to have a separate file/partition for each `PSP`). Then, I will apply the sort function (more specifically the `sortWithinPartitions` function)

Comment: Hi Ali, I think sortWithinPartitions will help only in case of Sort Merge Join. In your case I would try to use partitionBy() since all the previous failed.

Comment: Hi Ali, any change :)?

Comment: Hello @Alexandros I just posted the answer sorry for the delay